# OS X Yosemite HUD broken

Tags: finder, macos

[image]

As you can see, my brightness window has a mysterious line towards the top of it. Is this by design, or did I really break it? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: That's not by design, I've never seen anything like that in all the time I've worked with Macs.

Comment: Just a line or any other side effects?

Comment: just a line... no side effects